# android tabs layout issue

Tags: java, android

I am making tabs layout in android. I am getting RuntimeException Error on this line `tabHost.addTab(spec);`. Where am I making mistake?

dashboard activity

```
public class DashboardActivity extends TabActivity {
Button btnLogout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
    btnLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    //Artist Tab
    intent = new Intent(this, Artists.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artist", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Songs
    intent = new Intent(this, Songs.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //Albums
    intent = new Intent(this, Album.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artist", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    //tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}   

}
```

here is my dashboard.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="WELCOME"
        android:textSize="40dip" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Logout Me"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</TabHost>
```

Here is my logcat output

```
05-29 05:02:12.556: D/dalvikvm(27476): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 40K, 50% free 2725K/5379K, external 0K/0K, paused 121ms
05-29 05:02:12.636: D/dalvikvm(27476): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 7K, 50% free 2743K/5379K, external 455K/518K, paused 25ms
05-29 05:02:12.781: D/CLIPBOARD(27476): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
05-29 05:02:34.136: D/dalvikvm(27476): GC_CONCURRENT freed 117K, 46% free 3054K/5639K, external 327K/661K, paused 7ms+2ms
05-29 05:02:34.151: D/AndroidRuntime(27476): Shutting down VM
05-29 05:02:34.151: W/dalvikvm(27476): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e578)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zafar.login/com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.zafar.login/com.zafar.login.Artists}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476): Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.zafar.login/com.zafar.login.Artists}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.resolveActivityInfo(ActivityThread.java:1461)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:277)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:691)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:341)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:226)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:29)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476):    ... 11 more
05-29 05:02:40.606: I/Process(27476): Sending signal. PID: 27476 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Sorry for being repetitive, but as the log says _have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare your `Activity`s in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<activity 
    android:name="com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log indicate error

`05-29 05:02:34.156: E/AndroidRuntime(27476): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zafar.login/com.zafar.login.DashboardActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.zafar.login/com.zafar.login.Artists}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Did you declared **Artists** activity in Manifest ?

Answer (score 0):

Declare Artist, Song and Album activity in manifest file. I think this example you are trying is from developer.android.com and there, they have not specified to include these activities in manifest file. Include them and your code should execute without any exceptions.

Thank you :)